# Looking for a cocotron example

Tags: cocotron

I have been having a lot of trouble getting cocotron to create a simple window app that can be compiled on the mac and will produce an that will run on the pc.  Does anyone have a link to a simple example that I could download where all the setting are correct?  This would really help me look and see what the differences are and help me see what I am doing wrong.  Anyone out there have anything like this?

Comment: Did you try this? http://www.allisonic.com/blog/426

Comment: Yeah that did help thanks.  I followed the instructions and got it to build but even when I compile the windows target it creates a .app in the windows deployment directory.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the TextEditor example from the Cocotron site: 
http://www.cocotron.org/Code/Examples/TextEditor/